# Joomla module vertical align

Tags: css, joomla

I have this **Custom HTML module** with 9 flags inserted in the position **mainmenu** as you can see here [www.jornaldalusofonia.pt](http://www.jornaldalusofonia.pt)

How can I give it CSS instructions so it stays vertically aligned in the middle of the bar.

Thank you,
Rui Farinha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Flex this is quite simple, just do the below:

```
#jsn-pos-mainmenu {
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

And then remove the extra margin top on the form input:

```
.jsn-modulecontainer[class*="display-"] form {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

**NOTE:** You must prefix your CSS for flex using [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) tool, or any tool you choose. Also note that flexbox does't work with older verisons of IE9 and below , also older versions of safari.

Comment: Hi,I need to do the same but for the position toolbar, I've tried changing #jsn-pos-mainmenu to #jsn-pos-toolbar but it didnt work...